# Skript value in Blob encrypted

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, blob, minecraft

I use the Skript plugin to code in Minecraft, with this plugin I added my variables into a database mySql. The objective is that my friend who code in java a mod for minecraft can pick up the values of the variables to display them.
The problem is that the value of the variables are in "Blob" and he can't read them because they are encrypted, we would like to put them in long or int or something who could be readed. I really understand nothing in PhpMyAdmin so if someone is able to help me I would be grateful. (Btw sorry for my english I'm french).

I would like to add that if I register my variable in string, he can read them but with some symbols like ▄¤HÆ and things like that.

If you want we can chat on Skype or mails or TeamSpeak, ... Thank you !

*There is a screen of my table where the blobs are registered :[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtp0b.png)

Comment: Welcome to `SO` Please elaborate your question for others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the charset used if characters are displayed wrong.
You should look into that.

For viewing you can use the cast function to change the data type of the value .

```
select cast(value as char) from schema_name.table_name ;
```

If you want your table to show the values you can change the data type of the column.

```
alter table table_name.schema_name
change column value value varchar(75);
#or
alter table table_name.schema_name
change column value value int;
```